# Image display issue in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code to display an image from folder fname ( upload/2017/05/fname)

```
 [php]
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/2017/05/fname/' );
echo $logo_dir . '-----<br />';
$images = glob( $logo_dir . "*.PNG" );
foreach( $images as $image ) {
echo "$image";
}
[/php]
```

but this shows only the path such as https://example.com/jobs/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/fname/—–

I want code that display all the images from the folder in a page.

Comment: Try wrapping <img> HTML tag?

Comment: @jacktheking still same results after <img>

Comment: `$logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/2017/05/fname/' );` it will  `https://example.com/jobs/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/fname/`'. you are trying image for post?

Comment: where is your file name?

Comment: @vel i just want to display these images (which is available in fname folder) from folder fname to a new page.

Comment: did you try `$images = glob( $logo_dir . "*.png" );`?

Comment: and `$images =  glob($logo_dir."*.{png}", GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: @vel code is [php]
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 

$logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/2017/05/KPK/' );
echo $logo_dir . '-----<br />';
$images = glob( $logo_dir . "*.png" );
foreach( $images as $image ) {
    echo"<img src="$image" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">";
}
[/php] and result is /home/mcqpagec/public_html/jobs/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/KPK/—–

Comment: it will get error? `$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); $logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/2017/05/KPK/' ); echo $logo_dir . '-----<br />'; $images = glob( $logo_dir . "*.png" ); foreach( $images as $image ) { echo"<img src="$image" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">"; } `

Comment: @vel there is no any error in error log, if you have any code that display the images, then please share

Comment: Just to give you a pointer about a potential issue in your code: The `glob` function does not work for the http(s) wrapper, so globbing is not supported with the URL as you try. This is why you only see the one "path" (actually an URL) which is from `echo $logo_dir`. The `glob` function needs a path on the file-system. See as well https://php.net/glob

Answer (score 0):

Please use,

```
$upload_dir['basedir']
```

instead of

```
$upload_dir['baseurl']
```

Because `baseurl` indicate URL of the directory and `basedir` indicate your server path.

change your code and try again. Hope It will work.

Thanks.

Comment: after add baseurl the result is still same

Comment: @hassanzeb, Try to use glob("img/thumb/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)  or glob("img/thumb/*.png)

Comment: the result is /home/mysite/public_html/jobs/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/fname/—–

Comment: stil the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to be displaying an  tag as @jacktheking and @vel say.

Just updated the answer by fixing the `<img/>` tag line. Note the uses of `['basedir']` and `['baseurl']`. The URL is for setting the  src, while the dir is used for retrieving the files. `basename()` is used for separating the file name from the full path.

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$base_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/2017/05/fname';
$logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/2017/05/fname' );
$images = glob( $logo_dir . '/*.png' );

foreach( $images as $image ) {
    echo '<img src="' . $base_url . '/' . basename( $image ) . '" />';
}
```

Comment: /home/example.com/public_html/jobs/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/fname/jobs-326x1024-326x1024.gif

Comment: @hassanzeb I just updated the answer, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();  
    $theme_root = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/2017/05/fname';
    $files_array = glob("$theme_root/*");

    foreach  ($files_array as $key => $img):

         $img =str_replace("/home/example.com/public_html/","https://example.com/",$img);
        $get_icons = '<li><img src="'.$img.'" /></li>';
        echo $get_icons;
    endforeach;

?>
```

it will return `D:\xampp\htdocs\demowp/wp-content/uploads/2017/2017/05/fname/I-Love-University--150x150.jpg`
you should replace `D:\xampp\htdocs\demowp/` to `http://yousite.com/`

Comment: the result is as follow /home/example.com/public_html/jobs/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/fname/jobs-326x1024-326x1024.gif  in a loop and not displaying image, thanks for your help

Comment: you should replace the url `/home/example.com/public_html/` to `https://example.com/`

Comment: can you post the value of `$img` after replaced url?

Comment: the reult is https://mcqpage.com/jobs/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/KPK/allama-iqbal-open-university-pakistan-jobs-326x1024.gif mcqpage.com is my website it pick the picture but the url is not valid.

Comment: i have used custum php website that is www.mcqpage.com but now i want to convert it in wordpress but facing alot of trouble

Comment: you should wrap within `img` tag like `$get_icons = '<li><img src="'.$img.'" /></li>'`;

Comment: [php]
      $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();  
    $theme_root = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/2017/05/KPK';
    $files_array = glob("$theme_root/*");

    foreach  ($files_array as $key => $img):

         $img =str_replace("/home/mcqpagec/public_html/","https://mcqpage.com/",$img);
        $get_icons = '<li><img src="'.$img.'" /></li>';
        echo $get_icons;
    endforeach;
echo"$img";
[/php] please this the complete code

Comment: replace this code echo"$img";  with echo $get_icons;

Comment: Just to give you a pointer about a potential issue in your code: The glob function does not work for the http(s) wrapper, so globbing is not supported with the URL as you try.